# Invoke method in another class, python

Tags: python, class, methods, pyqt

i'm not very deep into Python for now. But i have in my opinion very simple, but non googable question.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(659, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    ...Code Omitted...
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 370, 391, 31))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial",20))
    self.label.setStyleSheet("color:white")
    ...Code Omitted...
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    ...Code Omitted...
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def AddTextToString(self, text123):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow",text123))

class MyThread(QThread):
...Code Omitted...
    def run(self):
        ...Code Omitted...
        Ui_MainWindow().AddTextToString("Hello Word")
```

all i want to do, is to invoke a method, from another class with a passing variable from another method inside another class.

**AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'label'**

Comment: `Ui_MainWindow` is just a helper class that is "built" on a widget, the instance alone won't do anything; also, your indentation is not clear, and it seems like that function is at the wrong level. And, in any case, you can **NOT** access widgets from external threads, and you must use signals. You need to create the thread and connect its (custom) signal to the function that will actually set the text. Note that you should ***not*** manually edit pyuic files, but properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: yea, i see, sorry for indentation, but it's good at my side  
Actually, you are correct for 100% and right now everything is working fine, thanks a lot!
I was thinking about this as a class, and tried to build something comples, but it turned out that i could use the signals. Thank you!

Comment: The fact that it's good on your side doesn't change the result: we cannot know what is "good", and considering the utmost importance of indentation in python that cannot be ignored. Please *always* check the post preview (even when you [edit]), and ensure that you're properly [formatting code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Indentation needs to be fixed (specifically, `def setupUI`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the variable `self.label` is initialized once `setupUI` method is called not in `__init__` so you should call the `setupUI` method after initialization of `Ui_MainWindow`

Second You can't call `Ui_MainWindow().AddTextToString("Hello Word")` as `AddTextToString` is not static method and it modifies class variable..

You need to create object of `Ui_MainWindow` like `self.ui_window = Ui_MainWindow()` and call `self.ui_window.AddTextToString("Hello World")`